# Python Pandas vectorise find matching datetime from varying size

Tags: python, pandas

so my solution to what I thought would be a straightforward problem to solve within Python Pandas turns out to be terribly slow, for what will be, in just one moment, obvious reasons.

Imagine two dataframes:

```
stt       = datetime.strptime(args.stt_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
stp       = datetime.strptime(args.stp_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
time_loc  = pd.date_range(stt, stp, freq='T')
col_names = ['time_loc'     ,
             'time_utc'     ,
             'ObsType'      ,
             'Station'      ,
             'WindDir'      ,
             'WindSpd'      ,
             'WindGst'      ,
             'T'            ,
             'Td'           ,
             'MSLP'         ,
             'PrecipRate'   ,
             'PrecipAccm9am',
             'PrecipAccm24h',
             'CldAWS'       ,
             'VisAWS'       ,
             'VisObs'       ]
DF             = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)
DF['time_loc'] = time_loc
```

This is the first dataframe. It is much larger than the next dataframe. This big dataframe has one minute time steps. The following dataframe, "df", has the same column names as the big dataframe, "DF", but contains data sampled at varying intervals and is always smaller in size than the big. Most of the time the sample rate of the small, "df", dataframe is every 30 minutes, but some of the time it can be less than 30 minutes, but never less than a minute. Ok, hopefully, you see where this is going.

The following code is what is I am doing at present to find matching dates in the big dataframe, "DF", with that of the little dataframe, "df".

```
df = aus_metar.parseMETAR(f,pathIn)
for l1, row in df.iterrows():
    df_idx = df.iloc[l1]['time_loc']
    DF_idx = DF['time_loc'].index[DF['time_loc'] == df_idx]
    DF.iloc[DF_idx, DF.columns.get_loc('time_utc')]      = df.iloc[l1]['time_utc']
    DF.iloc[DF_idx, DF.columns.get_loc('ObsType')]       = df.iloc[l1]['ObsType']
    DF.iloc[DF_idx, DF.columns.get_loc('Station')]       = df.iloc[l1]['Station']
    DF.iloc[DF_idx, DF.columns.get_loc('WindDir')]       = df.iloc[l1]['WindDir']
    DF.iloc[DF_idx, DF.columns.get_loc('WindSpd')]       = df.iloc[l1]['WindSpd']
    DF.iloc[DF_idx, DF.columns.get_loc('WindGst')]       = df.iloc[l1]['WindGst']
    DF.iloc[DF_idx, DF.columns.get_loc('T')]             = df.iloc[l1]['T']
    DF.iloc[DF_idx, DF.columns.get_loc('Td')]            = df.iloc[l1]['Td']
    DF.iloc[DF_idx, DF.columns.get_loc('MSLP')]          = df.iloc[l1]['MSLP']
    DF.iloc[DF_idx, DF.columns.get_loc('PrecipRate')]    = df.iloc[l1]['PrecipRate']
    DF.iloc[DF_idx, DF.columns.get_loc('PrecipAccm9am')] = df.iloc[l1]['PrecipAccm9am']
    DF.iloc[DF_idx, DF.columns.get_loc('PrecipAccm24h')] = df.iloc[l1]['PrecipAccm24h']
    DF.iloc[DF_idx, DF.columns.get_loc('CldAWS')]        = df.iloc[l1]['CldAWS']
    DF.iloc[DF_idx, DF.columns.get_loc('VisAWS')]        = df.iloc[l1]['VisAWS']
    DF.iloc[DF_idx, DF.columns.get_loc('VisObs')]        = df.iloc[l1]['VisObs']
```

This solution is SLOW. Really, really slow!

Does anyone have any bright ideas on how to speed this up or maybe even vectorise this?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
stt       = datetime.strptime('2018-12-06 11:30', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
stp       = datetime.strptime('2020-10-31 23:30', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
col_names = ['time_loc'     ,
             'time_utc'     ,
             'ObsType'      ,
             'Station'      ,
             'WindDir'      ,
             'WindSpd'      ,
             'WindGst'      ,
             'T'            ,
             'Td'           ,
             'MSLP'         ,
             'PrecipRate'   ,
             'PrecipAccm9am',
             'PrecipAccm24h',
             'CldAWS'       ,
             'VisAWS'       ,
             'VisObs'       ]
DF = []    
for f in files:
        df = pd.read_pickle(os.path.join(pklPath,f))
        # df is matrix of 15 columns and N rows with datetimeindex
        # max sampling rate (frequency) of N is no less than 1 minute
        DF.append(df)
DF2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names, index=idx)
DF2.loc[DF[0].index] = DF[0].values
```

Results in:

> *** KeyError: "[Timestamp('2018-12-04 09:30:00'), Timestamp('2018-12-01 12:30:00'), .... Timestamp('2018-12-02 13:00:00')] not in index"

Comment: You're trying to replace the values of the big dataframe with the small dataframe's where the time index matches?

Comment: Yes. The big dataframe is essentially an empty (NaN) dataframe with the exception of the 'time_loc' column, which contains a time series of datetimes of every one minute between 'stt' and 'stp'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do, set datetimes as index for both dataframes and set the values of the smaller dataframe as a slice of the larger one. This implies that the columns are ordered in the same way. Provided they have the same name, you can simply :

```py
big_df = big_df.reindex(columns=small_df.columns)
```

Since that's out of the way, here comes my solution with an example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()

n = 100
N = 600

vals_5min = rng.integers(-100, -20, n)
colors_5min = rng.choice(["blue", "red", "yellow"], n)
vals = rng.integers(1, 100, N)
colors = rng.choice(["green", "white", "brown"], N)

idx_5min = pd.date_range("2010-01-01", periods=n, freq='5min')
idx = pd.date_range("2010-01-01", periods=N, freq='1min')

df_5min = pd.DataFrame({
    "vals_5min": vals_5min,
    "color": colors_5min
},
                       index=idx_5min)
df = pd.DataFrame({"vals": vals, "color": colors}, index=idx)

df.loc[df_5min.index] = df_5min.values
```

The logic happens at the end, with time indexes you can slices the big df only where it has the same index as the small df. Then set that slice as the values of the small df. In my example, only the small df has negative values and the colors don't match, after the last operation the head looks like that.

```
                     vals   color
2010-01-01 00:00:00   -49  yellow
2010-01-01 00:01:00    95   white
2010-01-01 00:02:00    67   brown
2010-01-01 00:03:00    43   brown
2010-01-01 00:04:00    81   white
2010-01-01 00:05:00   -80    blue
2010-01-01 00:06:00    88   green
2010-01-01 00:07:00    41   white
2010-01-01 00:08:00    54   green
2010-01-01 00:09:00    91   brown
2010-01-01 00:10:00   -66     red
2010-01-01 00:11:00    73   white
2010-01-01 00:12:00    78   brown
2010-01-01 00:13:00    18   white
2010-01-01 00:14:00    69   white
2010-01-01 00:15:00   -53     red
2010-01-01 00:16:00    76   white
2010-01-01 00:17:00    16   green
2010-01-01 00:18:00    54   brown
2010-01-01 00:19:00    12   green
2010-01-01 00:20:00   -37  yellow
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan. That's pretty slick! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @dpath2o That's great, tell me if it works and please do accept the answer if it does!

Comment: Unfortunately, my implementation of this has not worked ... I'm editing the initial entry to show again how I am doing this and the error.

Comment: @dpath2o You're getting the error because the indices aren't matching, you should look up the timestamps in the error and see why they're not in the big dataframe